# OpenLayers 4 wont display vector layer

Tags: typescript, dictionary, vector, openlayers, topojson

Im porting my map game from OpenLayers 3 and Dojo to Angular and OpenLayers 4. However map doesnt show any vector data i fill to vector layer through ol.format.TopoJSON

Map:

```
this.map = new ol.Map({
  layers: [
    this.vectorLayer,
  ],
  view: new ol.View({
    center: ol.proj.fromLonLat([19, 48]),
    extent: [-9999999999, -20920774, 99999999999, 18800987],
    zoom: 5,
    maxZoom: 11,
    minZoom: 3
  })
});
```

Vector Layer:

```
this.vectorLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({
  updateWhileAnimating: true,
  updateWhileInteracting: true,
  source: new ol.source.Vector({
    loader: function () {
      http.get(topoJsonUrl)
        .subscribe(data => self.setupData(data));
    }
  }),
  style: function (feature) {
    return self.fillCountry(true);
  }
});
```

Data preparation:

```
setupData(data): void {
  let features = this.dataFormat.readFeatures(data);
  this.vectorLayer.getSource().addFeatures(features);  
}

dataFormat = new ol.format.TopoJSON({defaultDataProjection: 'EPSG:3857'});

fillCountry(simple): any {
  let color = 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2)';
  let stroke = 'rgba(255,255,255, 1)';
  if (simple) {
    color = '#FFF8E1';
    stroke = 'rgba(0,0,0, 1)';
  }
  const s = new ol.style.Style({
    fill: new ol.style.Fill({
      color: color
    }),
    stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
      color: stroke,
      width: 0.4
    })
  });
  return s;
}
```

Map get its target in `ngOnInit()` .

When i try to add sample source like

```
this.vectorSource = new ol.source.Vector({
  url: 'https://openlayers.org/en/v4.6.5/examples/data/geojson/countries.geojson',
  format: new ol.format.GeoJSON()
});
```

map works fine.
Also when i look for my features from TopoJSON in source after map is loaded with debug console `this.map.getLayers().getArray()[0].getSource().getFeatures()` i see all features loaded (so it appears they are corrected loaded and parsed), but cannot see anything in view.

Thought it might be problem with asynchronous data loading, but features are added to vector layer through `addFeatures()` so i assume its correct approach.

Comment: If the features are there but you cannot see them, it is most likely a styling issue. Try using the default style or check that you actually set the correct style types.

Comment: through the time i tried that, but it wasnt styling issue. It looks like issue with loader part in source, because if i use url instead of loader it works fine. Hovewer i need some refactoring of feature in loader, so url doesnt suits me

Comment: I don't see any obvious mistakes. Maybe it's just a data problem, e.g. wrong projection or inverted coordinates. Anyway, we would need a minimal runnable example to help you.